# 3 monitors on hd4600

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have connected 3 monitors via DVI, DisplayPort and HDMI. However only DVI and HDMI show.

When I disconnect the monitor connected to the HDMI plug then the monitors on DVI and on DisplayPort work. If I reconnect HDMI then DP cuts off.

My motherboard is an [Asus B85M-E](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/B85ME/) which supports 3 displays. DP is connected to DP on monitor. No converter.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the DP monitor connected? A simple DP port cable from DP on the motherboard to the DP port on the monitor? Or via a powered convertor?

Comment: Did you try this - looks comprehensive - http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm

Comment: I had a similar situation.  My video card can support 4 DisplayPorts, but with passive DP to HDMI converters, it could not show more than 2 HDML signals.  This is because the video card had a limit to how many HDMI signals it could power.  The solution was to get an "active' DP to HDML converter.  Now I have 3 outgoing HDMI signals, just fine.  Your situation is a bit different, involving DVI and working with HDMI, but I'm throwing out the idea that using the right type of adapter might be a working solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

In BIOS there is a setting on primary graphics card. I had it on Auto and changed to iGpu. Now all monitors were recognized and working.